# Silently update mobile iron app

Tags: mdm, mobileiron

I have no experience with mobile iron but we are looking into possibilities of mobile iron updating our enterprise app without asking users to update it. Any related information is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you update this with the OS you're using? If it is Android, the device may also be useful depending on how the mdm is deployed (as a device owner, profile owner, or device administrator).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Send Message" Command(MobileIron Admin portal->App distribution page->Select the Enterpise App->Actions->Send Message)to push silent instal/updates of Apps.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a Send Message action anymore, or I can't find it. Has it been moved? Do you know the correct way to do this now?